# When I plug in headphones, my speakers mute, but nothing comes from the headphones

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

When I plug in headphones, my speakers mute, but nothing comes from the headphones. Also, there is a weird red light coming from my headphone jack. I am on a Macbook from late 2007, and have Ubuntu 11.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem since a week ago, on a Dell Studio XPS, also on 11.10. In the past I usually fixed it by adding

`options snd-hda-intel model=dell-eq` or `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6`

to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

but it's not working anymore.

Comment: Well, all of a sudden it's working, after doing the DKMS below and the options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6 above, for the hundredth time. Go figure.

Comment: First option solved this for my Dell studio XPS Studio 1647

Answer (score 1):

This is because the headphone output is controlled by the 'Speaker 1' volume, which is muted by default. To solve this, install `alsamixergui` and enable the 'Speaker 1' volume.

Answer (score 0):

I have a LG E500 with Ubuntu 11.10, I had normal sound on speakers, but when plug in headphones they mute, and to turn on sound I had to mute and unmute at the sound menu. So I found this easy solution,just installing a .deb package. I hope that it helps you!

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover all your bases, have you checked the output volume for your headphone jack? In a terminal run `alsamixer`. Use left/right arrow keys to scroll through the channels, up/down to adjust the levels.