# Sound problem on both Speakers and HeadPhones

Tags: sound, 13.04, alsa, headphones

I know there are a lot of questions like this here, but I tried them all and I couldn't make them work.

- I have a HP dv6-2190ep laptop.
- My sound card is HDA Intel  IDT 92HD75B3X5.
- My Ubuntu is 13.04.

I tried to add options on `alsa-base.conf` but I still don't have auto mute option.

I'm completely changing to Ubuntu from Windows and it is important to fix this. I'm around this for about 1 month.

Comment: Hi, I just resolved my problem following the steps provided here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Comment: I followed that link and my problem solve too, thank you.

Comment: Did you check [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)?

Comment: It would help if you could add the model # of the laptop to your question!

Comment: What audio card do you have? (`alsamixer`)

Comment: what hardware? tried 3.10rc1 (does not work with nvidia/amd/ati drivers)

Comment: When you brought the bar back up you get the headphones working?
And have you looked already at "System Settings..." > "Sound" and from there have you tried to switch between the Output devices available in the list?

Comment: I did, nothing seems to fix it.
Actually, in the system setting > Sound i can't even fix the problem.

Comment: your lappy speakers are working properly? Have you check for any problem in sound setting ?

Answer (score 7):

Try removing pulseaudio completely and installing alsa.

Check this out

**Remove Pulse Audio**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio
```

Reboot your computer or stop the pulseaudio daemon.

**Install alsa-mixer**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

If you don't get any sound output run

```
gnome-alsamixer
```

For more details go to [How to Remove PulseAudio & use ALSA in Ubuntu Linux?](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I now get no sound in my ubuntu 14.04!! This is the first time I have ever had problems with sound what is going on!!

Comment: Worked! Thanks. The link was just as helpful as your answer. :D

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem on my Asus K55vm laptop since 12.04. Although your solution does work, in laptops it will cause the sound to be transmitted by both the plugged headphones and the speakers. To make them work properly and only have sound come out of the headphones when plugged in or the speakers when headphones are not plugged in:

Run in terminal:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`

Find:

`[Element Headphone]`

Set it as:

```
[Element Headphone]
required-any = any
switch = on
volume = zero
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Find:

`[Element Desktop Speaker]`

Set it to:

```
[Element Desktop Speaker]
switch = on
volume = zero
```

**This works FOR ME BUT:** keep in mind that when you plug in your headphones their volume will be the volume they were the last time and when you unplug them the speakers volume will be the volume it was before you plugged in the headphones.

I hope this can also help someone with the same problem as me and thank you very much bozbezbozzel! Without you I would not have made it. :)

Comment: Thank's, very good solution. For me work perfectly Ubuntu 12.04 with card HDA Intel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running close to a vanilla install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS, try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`. Now I know those are very novice answers, but it may just work. My last suggestion is to go to this answer: [When I plug in headphones, my speakers mute, but nothing comes from the headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106063/when-i-plug-in-headphones-my-speakers-mute-but-nothing-comes-from-the-headphon) which is loosely related to the issue you are having. If this doesn't help, try going to the audio options in system settings and make sure you have the correct output selected.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [this page](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages).
2. Under the "Source label", check which DKMS package that is corresponding to your current distribution series (in this case `precise`) and click the leftmost arrow to expand that section.
3. Under the new section "Package files", click the file ending with ".deb", download and install it by executing execute this command: `sudo dpkg -i <file name>`.
4. Reboot.

[Further information.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS)

Answer (score 1):

this should work click the link [How do I change which audio jacks are used for input and output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output) and this should work for the new 13.04 
[Python script to change the jack from input to output does not work in 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289042/python-script-to-change-the-jack-from-input-to-output-does-not-work-in-13-04)

Comment: Thanks for the quit answer and this does help a bit, but not as expected. I identified the PIN and enabled "out", but sound appears only for a second and goes silent again

Comment: try saving it look on the http://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output link and it tells you how to save it do not revert it when done just click no

Comment: Thank you for your help, it needed a reboot and some try and error, but now it works. The only thing, which isn't perfect now is, that settings->sound cannot switch between headphones/speakers. But this is okay, since I exported 2 scrips for enabling / disabling headphones / speakers :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This worked for me.

Try this:

Go to: `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out the following line with a `#` sign:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got an HP Pavilion dv6 with beats audio, and I had the exact same problem. Alsamixer muted the 'Speaker' volume when I plugged my headphones in, and apparently, that is the volume the headphones use. I found the following workaround:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf
```

You'll find the line:

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = off
volume = off
```

Change it to:

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = on
volume = merge
```

Now, do the same with `usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones-2.conf`
and reboot. Now your headphones should work. However, when you unplug them the sound from your internal speakers will be at the same volume your headphones were at. So while this does not make the audio work as well as before, at least it doesn't mute your headphones all the time.

EDIT: Only one of the headphone jacks (the one at the front) is working for me, even though I changed headphones-2 as well. No idea why.